# child_process.spawn stdin pipe depth?

Tags: node.js, pipe, spawn

The following program spawns a `sleep` process to wait for a hour, then with `sleep` in the background, the program loops writing a string to the external `sleep` process.

I am well aware that the `sleep` doesn't read anything at all, it is only selected for the demonstration purpose. (A)

My program loops 279 times and then pauses. The go-and-stop is expected, but I cant figure out what happens after exact 279 loops, like a buffer get full.

- Where is that buffer defined?
- Can I make it smaller?
- Can I somehow ask the spawn object how much outstanding data I have waiting in the write queue?

If I change `"0123456789"` to just a single `"X"`, it still loops 279 turns, so it isn't simply a unix pipe getting filled. First example managed to write 2790 bytes, the second stopped after one tenth.

```
var child_process = require('child_process')

var p = child_process.spawn('/bin/sleep', ['3600']);

var cnt = 0;
function do_tick() {
  cnt++;
  console.log(cnt);
  p.stdin.write("0123456789", null, function(){
    setTimeout(do_tick, 1);
  });
}
do_tick();
```

The trivial: LinuxMint 17.2 x86_64, node.js v0.10.25

> (A) My real world problem is something with feeding PCM audio to a live
>   stream at a propper rate and with out getting too far ahead, much more complicated.

Comment: Just downloaded a fresh node v4.2.1 and gave it a spin, exactly the same result, exactly 279 cycles

Comment: The only thing I can tell you for sure is that `p.stdin` writes first 279 chunks to some underlying device, but all chunks started from 280th are being buffered by `p.stdin` itself (i.e. by `WriteableStream` class).

Comment: As for your problem, the only thing I can suggest is to rely on `WritableStream` internal buffer, [checking return value of `p.stdin.write` and waiting for `'drain'` event when it's `false`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain). `p.stdin.write` will keep returning `true` as long as its internal `16KiB` buffer isn't full.

Comment: As for `p.stdin.write` callback, it's fired when your data is flushed out of `WritableStream` buffer into an underlying system. So, from `p.stdin` point of view first  chunks of your data were successfully sent somewhere.